# Windows Forms - Manual Form Positioning

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have the following code on visual studio 2012, and I have also changed the properties to manual positioning.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        }
   }
}
```

It was supposed to position my window's top left corner at (100, 100) co-ordinates.

I got this example on the net, where they were using Visual Studio 2010. Could it be the case that there is something I have to do to achieve the same results in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Are you sure that Form1_Load is executing? Thats a pretty basic operation that should work.  I just tried it in my environment (2012) with various settings for Form.StartupLocation and it worked fine.

Comment: No, the code is the same for both.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on Form1_Load to see if it's being hit?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, it would be better to just set this up in the Form's designer.

Set [`StartPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) to [`FormStartPosition.Manual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx), and the `Location` as needed.  This will cause the form to be *created* in the proper place, where your code (once working properly) will actually move the form within it's `Load` event handler.

> i got this example on the net where they were using visual studio 2010 can it be that there is something i have to do for me to achieve the same results in visual studio 2012?

This code should actually function properly, both in VS 2010 and 2012 (Windows Forms code works the same in all versions of the .NET Framework).  Make sure you have `Form1_Load` actually set to be the `Form.Load` event handler.  If this isn't done in the designer, you could add it to the constructor manually:

```
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Load += Form1_Load; // Needs to be setup in designer or here...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this line `I have also changed the properties to manual positioning` before, if so, there is no reason for your code not working unless the `Form1_Load` is not registered with `Load` event of your form.

Comment: i just took the code and placed it to the constructor and it worked i have to see y my form1_load is not working. thanks for your help guys , i was starting to think that i was losing it or 2012 works different

Comment: @immanuelx - if you figured out it yourself you can post your answer and mark it as accepted.